# Police raid home of bitcoin 'founder'

Tags: altcoin, legal, politics

Recently, [WIRED](http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2015-12/09/bitcoin-founder-craig-steven-wright-police) released an article about an alleged creator of Bitcoin being raided by the police. Briefly, the article mention the following:

> **Police raid home of bitcoin 'founder' Craig Steven Wright**
>   *09 December 15*
>
> Police have raided the home of a 44-year-old Australian alleged to be
>   the creator of cryptocurrency bitcoin.
>   Craig Steven Wright, a tech
>   entrepreneur living in Sydney, was labelled by WIRED US as the
>   mysterious 'founder' of the digital currency -- that has previously
>   only been known under the pseudonym Satoshi Nakamoto.
>   Since Wright
>   was named as being the potential originator behind bitcoin police have
>   raided his home and office, although the Guardian reports the raids
>   surround tax issues and not the bitcoin revelations specifically.

1) What crimes Satoshi Nakamoto has done in order to be chased by the police? This applies only to Australia or around the globe?
2) Nowadays there are several hundreds of other cryptocurrencies. All those developers are also liable of such punishments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [yesterday's article about this in The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2015/dec/09/bitcoin-founder-craig-wrights-home-raided-by-australian-police), the Australian Federal Police released the following statement about the raid, stating that the raid was not related to any involvement that wright may (or may not) have had in inventing bitcoin:

*“The AFP can confirm it has conducted search warrants to assist the Australian Taxation Office at a residence in Gordon and a business premises in Ryde, Sydney. This matter is unrelated to recent media reporting regarding the digital currency bitcoin.”*

The article goes on to reference the Australian Tax Office's involvement in the raid, and a recent interview between the ATO and Wright which focused on Wright's bitcoin holdings.  Capital gains on the sales of appreciated bitcoins are [subject to tax](https://www.ato.gov.au/General/Gen/Tax-treatment-of-crypto-currencies-in-Australia---specifically-bitcoin/) in Australia, so some are speculating the raid could be about back taxes that Wright may be subject to from his bitcoin holdings.